# PubSub lib for c#

Tags: c#, python, design-patterns

Is there a c# library which provides similar functionality to the [Python PubSub](http://wiki.wxpython.org/PubSub) library? I think it's kind of an Observer Pattern which allows me to subscribe for messages of a given topic instead of using events.

Answer (score 3):

These may be a bit heavy for you depending on your needs but:
http://www.nservicebus.com/
http://blog.phatboyg.com/masstransit/

Answer (score 1):

Note, if you have events for message notification, there are many options for dependancy injection / inversion of control.  See [Spring.Net](http://www.springframework.net/) and [Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/container/) as two popular frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Again, my be overkill, but the [OSE](http://ose.sf.net) library allows thins kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are several offerings on NuGet:  https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=pubsub